IntelliJ: move caret to begin/end of variable shortcut
Is there shortcut to move caret to begin/end of variable in IntelliJ?
I mean entire variable, not word like Ctrl + Arrow do.
$foo['foo']['foo']['foo']['foo']


There are no such bundled actions as far as I'm aware (my understanding of what is available). Plus, using your example, the variable here is just $foo, the rest is accessing specific elements.

As a possible alternative (not just a few presses, but still like 2x faster than Ctrl + Right in this case). How about using Edit | Extend Selection few times in a row until it selects the whole $foo['foo']['foo']['foo']['foo'] thing and then just Arrow Right -- the caret will end up at the end with no selection. The best idea I have for this...
